# CCSpriteFrameCache loading black image in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am generating different animated images integrated using texturepacker.

I am using the .plist and .png file in my code as below.  Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes the display animated image is black. I also clear/rebuilt my project and ran but also got black animated image sometimes.

TexturePacker generated .plist and .png as below

[image]

code as below.

```
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sheetPng-ipadhd-hd.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sheetPng-ipadhd-hd.png"];

    [self addChild:spriteSheet];


    /* Gather the list of frames(sprite) */

    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"M0%d.png",i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:2.0f];

    manSprite=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"M01.png"];
    [self resizeSprite:manSprite toWidth:180 toHeight:250];
    manSprite.position=ccp(375, 0);



    id firstRepeat  = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim] times:3];

    [manSprite runAction:firstRepeat];

    [background addChild:manSprite];

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild: background];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely something wrong with your file extensions. It seems they all have an extraneous `-hd` suffix added.

The filenames should be:

- sheetPng
- sheetPng-hd
- sheetPng-ipadhd